# ASP.NET MVC. Использование [Authorize(Roles = "Роль"), имея старый string Roles в проекте

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В проекте до меня использовалась модель `User`:

```
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

`Role`:

```
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

На ней уже много что написано, но сейчас я банально хз как это применить к авторизации, можно сказать что это сделано под админку(года так с 2013-2014). Принцип примерно такой(Зашел под админом - держи доступ в админку. Не админ? - Не пущу)

```
if(UserCurrentRole == "Администратор")
{
   действия
}
```

Сейчас разделяю авторизацию и добавляю виды пользователей и хочу из разграничивать через `[Authorize(Role = "Продавец"]` на контроллере(условно)

Можно ли как то применить эту модель `Role` на `[Authorize]`?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете вписывать в атрибут `Authorize(Role` любую текстовую строку, какая вам нравится. Хотите `продавец` - ок, пусть будет продавец.

Главное, не забудьте потом пройти в таблицу базы данных и вставить эту строку в таблицу ролей (штатно её название dbo.AspNetRoles) и указать в таблице dbo.AspNetUserRoles какие пользователи входят в эту роль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом НА ДАННОМ ЭТАПЕ какая разница какой у вас класс используется - типовой класс из библиотеки identity или ваш кастомный? Никакой. Админка работала все эти годы, значит, как-то была настроена: просто добавьте новую роль продавец в таблицу БД, навесьте `[Authorize(Role = "Продавец"]` на любой тестовый экшн/контроллер и убедитесь сами, что видно только пользователям из нужных групп.

Comment: Ок. Я попробую, но там она работала на банальной проверке - if(UserCurrentRole == "Администратор") { действия }

Comment: @AskAlexandria По идее от того, что вы переделаете этот if на атрибут `[Authorize(Role = "Администратор"]` всё продолжит работать и далее, но я бы на вашем месте протестировал бы предварительно и разобрался в коде.